# why is my split not splitting each element up?

Tags: python, split

very basic question, the output of my code below is ['201453'] but I want to get ['2','0','1','4','5','3']; why is it not splitting correctly?

```
int = 201453
string_int = str(int)

x = string_int.split()

print(x)
```

Comment: no need for split just cast it to list x = list(string_int)

Comment: split only splits when there is a delimiter, which you pass in, such as a comma or the default white space.

Comment: And please don't use keywords like 'int' as variable name. Also have a look at the str.split() function. It requires a separator which is a whitespace by default. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly convert into a list using:

```
x = list(string_int)
```

or using list comprehension:

```
x = [l for l in string_int]
```

Comment: Thanks, this does solve my problem. But why wasn't split working in my case? Or rather, how can I make it output each character separately?

Comment: As in the docs, the split method requires a delimiter, if you do not specify one like x.split() , python consider consecutives whitespaces. [str split doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) @Kwanchong

Answer (score 0):

All strings can also be used as list. So your `string_int` is already a list:

```
for x in string_int:
    print(x)
```

will print

```
2
0
1
4
5
3
```